# What can I use instead of a screw

Tags: car

Well I have a phone case that has tiny screws to keep the case intact because there are 3 pieces to the case that are screwed in and today I took the case off and lost omen of the screws now the case isn’t screwed together properly what can I use instead of the tiny screw to hold the case together please help.

Comment: Hi ArmaanSandhu, Welcome to Lifehacks.SE.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you are not going to open it again, just press the case into the right position then add some glue to the screw holes and let it cure.
Normal fast glue should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use tape or velcro if you need to remove it constantly, otherwise, use zonethin's suggestion.

By tape I mean like tape the case to the phone on the outside or inside (double-sided tape) and by velcro I mean put one side on the inside of the case and the other on the phone. For velcro you might need something else to keep the case from moving.

Comment: Can you add any detail or an image to help explain what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

My friend, there is no hack, you go find a screw. Go online, go to the manufactures site, go to a local electronics store or see if you can find a screw around your house that will fit. Anything other then the screw is going to be a **permanent** attachment or cause some kind of damage to the phone.